# Children's Fantasy Book involving village of dwarves fighting dragons and tug-of-war

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this early/mid 90's, the book I am looking for is a collection of illustrated short stories. The book itself was large in size (oversized) and filled with illustrations. I read the Indonesian translation, but I believe it is translated from English. I think the title of the book itself contained some variation of the word "Giant Picture book" or something to that effect. Some plot elements involve:

- a village of dwarves being invaded by a tribe of dragons (I think they are non-flying dragons)
- an all-out war was about to break out, with each side preparing an army with siege engines, etc. There's a whole page dedicated to showing different army units.
- one of the dragons ate some sort of herb and gained the ability to fly (or breathe fire)
- the dwarves sent a saboteur group consisting of caterpillars to eat away the wings of said dragon while he was sleeping
- the fight between the dwarves and the dragons ended up being decided by a tug-of-war contest, in which a Fairy figure intervened and used a giant prism to burn the middle of the rope
- there's also side stories about 7(?) fairies visiting the dwarves' village and one of them ended up being transformed into a mermaid, and one of them was killed while transformed into a songbird form.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the book series, it's called the *[The Woodland Folk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Woodland_Folk)* series by Tony Wolf.

The particular stories about the dragons come from the *[The Woodland Folk Meet Dragons](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2096873.The_Woodland_Folk_Meet_Dragons)* book.

I googled for *fairy tug of war dragon dwarf* and this popped up. The link gave me the information about the author and that was enough for me to search and buy a copy of the book

Comment: Excellent ! How did you find it again? And you will be able to accept your self answer in about 44 hours by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: I googled for "fairy tug of war dragon dwarf" and [this](https://www.pinterest.com/vedadsgn/tony-wolf-illustrations/) popped up. The link gave me the information about the author and that was enough for me to search and buy a copy of the book! Now that I have a child of my own I have an excuse to get a copy :)

Comment: Excellent! I've added that to your answer for future people (it helps teach people how to search) as well as links to the books.